# Deploying React & Node.JS as a service Linux Ubuntu 14

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, systemd, production

Have a Node.Js API and a React app semi finished. Working on deploying to get the development cycle churning. Currently using npm start for viewing the react server during development. Same for the Node API. When deployed to AWS EC2 I am building in the most basic fashion, npm build pushing to a 'release' folder.

Once the deploy folder is up, I can go into it and run serve -s release
This gets me up and running. I can do the same for api server.

To get the apps running as a service, for the api, I can see how I can build a systemd process and run that with no issue.

For the react app, is there an easy way to run that server as a system... I'm new to this stack, so I might be confused. I have read in some places that once you've built your react app that you need to serve it out via apache or nginx? (e.g. in development it hosts itself, in production, you need to serve it) Is that sort of the general idea - build with local hosting, deploy with a production webhost?

Help appreciated. This is my last major issue before I can get Jenkins running a nice pipeline for deployment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already running a NodeJs server, It would be a good idea to host your ReactJs App in the NodeJs App itself.

You can pipline in the Jenkins to Build the ReactJs App first and the move it to static serving folder in the server and then you just need to deploy the NodeJs app in which ever environment that you want.